# How to truncate table using Telerik OpenAccess ORM?

Tags: .net, telerik, openaccess, telerik-open-access

I've tried to

```
ObjectScope.GetSqlQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE %table_name%", null, null).Execute();
```

and

```
ObjectScope.GetOqlQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE %ClassName%Extent").Execute();
```

The first row does nothing. And the second throw Exception:

```
line 1:10: unexpected token: ["TABLE",<42>,line=1,col=10]
Original Query: TRUNCATE TABLE DayExtent
```

Comment: Shouldn't you provide the table name instead of a variable?

Comment: Of course, In real code I provide table name. I've used %table_name% as a placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

The method ExecuteDDLScript doesn't make a difference between DDL and DML script. It only requires that there are no open object scopes.

```
        IObjectScope scope = ObjectScopeProvider1.GetNewObjectScope();
        //do something here
        scope.Dispose();
        string tableToTruncate = "SOME_TABLE";
        scope.Database.GetSchemaHandler().ExecuteDDLScript(string.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE {0}", tableToTruncate));
        scope = ObjectScopeProvider1.GetNewObjectScope();
        //do something again
```

Hope that helps.